# Return a list of suggested words if two strings match

Tags: java, autocomplete

I have class called ItemList, which is used to provide a list of suggested words for an auto-complete textfield. So as the user types a letter, a dropdown menu appears with a list of suggested words.

I'm having trouble with the code required for this functionality.

```
public List<Interface> SuggestedListOfWords(String prefix) {


        int i = 0;
        List<Interface> suggestedListOfWords = null;

        while(i != wordsList.size()) {

            String wordElement = wordsList.elementAt(i);
            Item tempItem = new Item(wordElement);
            //String item = wordsList.elementAt(i);
            String itemName = tempItem.name;
            int compareResult = itemName.compareTo(prefix);

            if(compareResult == 0) {



            }

            i++;
        }

        return suggestedListOfWords;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
for (String s : wordsList) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix))
                phrases.add(s);
        }
```

Phrases is of type `List<Interface>`
It's complaining about the add statement here?

Comment: And what _specifically_ is giving you grief?

Comment: the compareto section, im not quit sure how i go about getting a list of words and adding them to the suggestListOfWords List

Comment: First, `suggestedListOfWords` should be an actual list, not null. Second, you don't want to add the word only if they're equal, but if a possible word *starts* with what's already been typed (I'd assume). Third, why not just iterate through the wordsList like `for (String w : wordsList)`? And yep, a *trie* would be more efficient but... let's get *something* working first.

Comment: You don't get a *list* of words in the `compareTo` section, the entire loop is what builds the list of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with

```
            phrases.add(s);
```

is that `phrases` is a `List < Interface >` ,
and `s` is a `String`.

`phrases` holds `Interfaces`, and you're trying to put a `String` in it.

Comment: so would it be better to just have a list of type string?

Comment: @EI756 - yes, it would at least compile!  You'll need to change the method signature to return List<String> as well.

Comment: right but is it not possible to have a list of type interface, and instatiate that list like List<Interface> list1 = new List<Interface>(); ?

Comment: @EI756 - yes, but then you can't put strings in it.  (I don't know what Interface is, but it doesn't matter in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

A [`Trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a good data structure for this sort of thing.